# Is there a way to use strings as separators in writetable() - Julia

Tags: csv, dataframe, julia, delimiter, separator

When using writetable() to write a Data Frame to a file, I would like to be able to have the delimiter be a space then a comma (i.e. " ," as the delimiter). I know writetable() only has the option to have a single char as the separator argument. Is there a possible workaround to be able to have a string as the delimiter?

Or, is it possible to simply add a space after every single data point in the data frame and then output it as normal to a .csv file, therefore essentially having the " ," delimiter in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `writedlm` function if you convert your DataFrame to an Array:

```
using DataFrames
A = DataFrame(rand(3,3));
B = convert(Array, A);
writedlm("/path/to/file.txt", B,  ", ")
```

To include a header you can use something like this:

```
f = open("/path/to/file.txt", "w")
writedlm(f, names(A)', ", ")
writedlm(f, B,  ", ")
close(f)
```

Note1: Don't forget the `'` transpose operation on `names(A)'`

Note2: soonish, I believe that `writedlm` will directly have a `header_string` option.  See [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/10284).

Comment: Ah, so simple. Thanks a lot!