# Outputting strings without quotation marks when using writetable() with DataFrames.jl in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

The default for writing strings in DataFrames to a file using writetable is that they are surrounded by quotation marks:

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(letters=["A","B","C"],numbers=[1,2,3])
writetable("df_file", df, separator='\t')
```

produces the following file:

```
"letters"   "numbers"
"A" 1
"B" 2
"C" 3
```

There is an option to change the quotemark character:

```
writetable("df_file", df, separator='\t', quotemark='.')

.letters.   .numbers.
.A. 1
.B. 2
.C. 3
```

but this doesn't work if no character is specified

```
writetable("df_file", df, separator='\t', quotemark='')
ERROR: syntax: invalid character literal
```

My question is: how can I write strings without any quotation mark character at all? This would be the output I would need:

```
letters numbers
A   1
B   2
C   3
```

I'm currently using Julia version 0.4.1, DataFrames package version 0.6.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [GitHub](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl/issues/811) discussion, the creators of the DataFrames package do not trust users with this kind of power to have control over their output.

My personal recommendation would be to just convert to `Array` and then use Julia's `writedlm()` which *does* trust users to know what they want to write to file:

```
writedlm(FileName, convert(Array,df), '\t')
```

To include a header you can use something like this:

```
open(FileName, "w") do f
    writedlm(f, names(df)', '\t')
    writedlm(f, convert(Array,df), '\t')
end
```

See also this related question with a similar answer: [Is there a way to use strings as separators in writetable() - Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38061746/is-there-a-way-to-use-strings-as-separators-in-writetable-julia?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for this - at least that explains why there's no option to remove quotation marks. Your workaround works for me.

Comment: @IanMarshall Yeah, it wouldn't have been my choice to write the package like that, but the authors are very smart people and I think they are aiming it at a very general audience.

Answer (score 3):

I would be tempted to just write a quickie somewhat like this:

```
julia> n, p = size(df)
(3,2)

julia> open("/tmp/df_file.txt", "w") do f
            for i in 1:n
               for j in 1:p
                  write(f, string(df[i, j]))
                  write(f, "\t")
               end
               write(f, "\n")
             end
        end
```

or if I had more time I might start writing something like this (a modified version of the source of the `writetable` function):

```
julia> function myprinttable(io::IO,
                           df::AbstractDataFrame;
                           header::Bool = true,
                           separator::Char = ',',
                           quotemark::AbstractString = "\"",
                           nastring::AbstractString = "NA")
           n, p = size(df)
           etypes = eltypes(df)
           if header
               cnames = DataFrames._names(df)
               for j in 1:p
                   print(io, quotemark)
                   print(io, cnames[j])
                   print(io, quotemark)
                   if j < p
                       print(io, separator)
                   else
                       print(io, '\n')
                   end
               end
           end
           quotestr = quotemark
           for i in 1:n
               for j in 1:p
                   if ! (isna(df[j],i))
                       if ! (etypes[j] <: Real)
                           print(io, quotemark)
                           DataFrames.escapedprint(io, df[i, j], quotestr)
                           print(io, quotemark)
                       else
                           print(io, df[i, j])
                       end
                   else
                       print(io, nastring)
                   end
                   if j < p
                       print(io, separator)
                   else
                       print(io, '\n')
                   end
               end
           end
           return
       end
julia> open("/tmp/df_file.txt", "w") do f
          myprinttable(f, df, header=true, separator='\t', quotemark="")
       end
```

(Mostly untested.)

which just changes `quotemark` from Char to String. (I'm still getting used to Julia's use of Char instead of single-character Strings in certain places.